# Why does classification theory restrict to complete first-order theories?

Tags: logic, soft-question, model-theory

Why is one just interested in classifying (the models of) complete theories?

For example, the [wikipedia page on stable theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_theory) writes:

> One goal of classification theory is to divide all *complete* theories into those whose models can be classified and those whose models are too complicated to classify, and to classify all models in the cases where this can be done.

One could state this research problem also for arbitrary theories: for which theories is it possible to classify the models?

Why does one mainly restrict research for complete theories?

Comment: Those are two very different questions ...

Comment: ...and I think each of them on its own is too broad! @NoahSchweber

Comment: I'm confused by the word "just" in the first question, and I can see several ways to interpret this question. Can you clarify what you're asking? As Noah says, it would be better to ask these questions separately - and you should include more context for both of them, and frame each of them so it's more clear what you're looking for. For example, I can answer the second question by saying "There are lots of natural examples of NIP theories, and there are lots of theorems you can prove about general NIP theories." Does that satisfy you? If not, make your question more specific.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Second answer satisfies me. Edited the first question.

Comment: The question is much better now. I voted to reopen. I also edited your title to be more informative - I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that it's easier: complete theories are simpler to work with (since any two models are elementarily equivalent - this gives us tools like elementary amalgamation, uniqueness of saturated models in the cardinalities where they exist, etc.), and restricting the classification problem to the complete theories reduces the scope of the work we have to do. Of course, even this restricted problem is already quite hard! And it leads to interesting mathematics, much of which works better in the context of a complete theory than outside that context. So most model theorists are happy to stick to complete theories.

Also, there is a sense in which the problem of classifying the models of arbitrary theories reduces to the problem of classifying the models of complete theories. Given an arbitrary theory $T$, and a model $M\models T$, the theory $\text{Th}(M) = \{\varphi\mid M\models \varphi\}$ is a complete theory extending $T$. So if you want to understand all the models of $T$, you can first understand all the completions of $T$, and then understand all the models of each completion $T'$ of $T$.

Another way of saying the same thing: If you want to classify all the models of a theory $T$, a natural (but fairly coarse) invariant to start with is the complete theory of each model. And then we can search for finer invariants just within the models of that complete theory.

I should mention that there is quite a bit of work (much of it by Shelah) on classification theory outside the context of complete first-order theories: e.g. classification theory for universal classes, classification theory over a predicate, infinitary logics, AECs, etc.